# Is it possible to perform a comparison to a control group with a non-parametric post-hoc test in R?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test, dunnett

Is it possible to perform a comparison to a control group with a non-parametric post-hoc test in R? I am familiar with various post-hoc tests such as Dunn and Conover, but I'm not sure how to implement a comparison to a control group using these methods in R. Any guidance or resources on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, You can use any nonparametric test and correct the associated pvalues. Adding a concrete example may be helpful here.

Comment: I am looking for a dunett test  but for non parametric

Comment: To re-iterate what @utobi said, an appropriate approach is to just use e.g. Dunn (1964) test, and use only those comparisons that are of interest.  You may want to then apply a *p*-value correction, again only on those comparisons that are of interest.

Comment: You can also see the documentation for the PMCMRplus package in R.  The following tests may be of interest: *kwManyOneConoverTest*, *kwManyOneDunnTest*, *kwManyOneNdwTest*.